# wso2 balana policy information

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

hi i am planning to use wso2 balana for externalizing authorization. I have a doubt on this. my doubt is when pdp send response after checking with policy file is it possible to get attribute level informations based on actions. Output will look something like below

customer info: firstname: read, edit,delete
                lastname : read
                designation: read,edit

so i need a response on attribute level with different actions. is it possible to evaluate a policy and get a response as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes..  It is possible. You can send any information within XACML response as Advices and Obligations. [This](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/07/12/what-is-new-with-xacml-3-0/) explains some info about Obligations and Advice with XACML 3.0. Basically you can send a user's attributes using it. If you are using Balana, There is sample that returns Advices with the response. You can find sample details from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/08/16/xacml-sample-for-on-line-trading-application/). If i found more details, will let you know.

Comment: However , with my  current implementation i want to receive the list of all the actions on a particular resource user is allowed to do. I,e  user would send only resource name to PDP and , its PDP which will send all the actions user is allowed to perform on the resource.  how can I handle this ?

Comment: I guess,  you need to retrieve allowed actions or resources per particular user. This is also can be done with XACML multiple decision profile. Here you may need to know the all actions and resources... I guess you can read this blog... http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/12/06/xacml-based-access-control-for-web-application/ It explains how you can achieve this

Comment: I am referring this link http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/12/09/multiple-decision-profile-hierarchical-resources/   to implement my requirement  will it solve my issue ? or its a different scenario than mine ?

Comment: In your case, you are sending resources, User name in to the PDP and you want to receive the actions that can be done by the user? I guess, If you know the all actions (if actions are pre-defined). You can use multiple decision profile. Where you can send all pre-defined actions   http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/12/06/multiple-decision-profile-repeated-attribute-categories/

Comment: Predefined actions ? you mean those actions must be defined in the policy ?if so actions must be suffixed with the resource for the identification of {resource and action pair} ?

Comment: Lastly , if I am sending User Name, resource and actions to PDP , whether am I supposed to write Different Policy or the same Policy for the Above Scenario will handle ?

Comment: No.. Predefined actions means that the actions in your system.. I guess, better to go through the sample that i post above... XACML request is created with all actions that can be in your system... As an example, there can be actions such as read, write, delete in the system.  We send XACML request with them,  then after it returns with allowed actions

Comment: Let me not confuse you , i will send Resource(Employee) and User name to PDP and PDP has to send me all the actions associated with each attribute. Ex. Resource -EmployeeInfo . Attributes :Name (edit,view) ,Age(view), Address (View,Edit,Delete ).

Comment: just confirm me about above case. if i am sending subject name, resource name, list of actions to pdp is it possible to get a response something like above where actions allowed for each attribute is separated. is there any sample available representing exact scenario?